# C++: Uninitialized Variable Output Is 0 in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, initialization

I'm in a very rudimentary beginner's programming course, focusing on C++. We're currently being taught about member variables vs local variables. To that end, I've written this very simple program, to see what the output would be when a local variable is declared but uninitialized and given the same name as a member variable that *has* been initialized.

```
class myclass
{
    public:
        void getvalues();
        myclass();
    private:
        int count;
};

myclass::myclass()
{
    count = 100;
}

void myclass::getvalues()
{
    int count;
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    myclass foo;
    foo.getvalues();

    return 0;
}
```

My expectation is that I would get some garbage output of some very large random number. Instead, the output is `0`. Any particular reason why this is? I'm using Xcode, if this makes a difference.

Comment: I cannot imagine that this behavior is defined. Have you tried using other compilers, such as g++, and seeing if you get the same results?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be 0? It's allowed to be anything, and 0 is anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially this is undefined behavior. But some environments will zero out memory. While other will leave it uninitialized. One thing you can count on is this not behaving the same in all environments (e.g., visual studio, gcc, etc.)